# Which import is used for SurfaceHolder in SurfaceView.java

Tags: android, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I copy the following code from Android's SurfaceView.java

I can see that SurfaceHolder is used in the SurfaceView.java:

```
public SurfaceHolder getHolder() {
        return mSurfaceHolder;
    }
```

However, I can't see which one of the following imports is used for SurfaceHolder. Can anyone explain to me . Thanks!

```
package android.view;
import com.android.internal.view.BaseIWindow;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.CompatibilityInfo.Translator; 
import android.graphics.Canvas; import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your surface view is under package android.view; 
and SurafaceHolder is also under same package so no import required :)

SurafceHolder derived form View
so you shoud use 
 import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

Comment: my question is SurfaceView.java uses SurfaceHolder in its code. where is the import?

Comment: Thank you  beacuse you made me to think
and i got the answer your surface view is under package android.view;
and SurafaceHolder is also under same package so no import required :)